# Is there a grub2 command to have a display pull and plug effect?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, grub, hdmi, vga

So, I have a strange situation with my laptop.

My laptop display panel got damaged. So, I removed the display along with LVDS connector and assumed that the laptop will redirect the BIOS and VIDEO screens to VGA and HDMI outputs. But it hasn't. The laptop still thinks that it has LVDS panel (xrandr and windows displays LVDS) and won't show BIOS on VGA or HDMI monitor ever. Luckily I had preferable settings in Bios before the display got damaged and I continue to keep them as is.

- So BIOS won't show on VGA / HDMI ever.
- GRUB will show on VGA / HDMI when I unplug the cable and replug immediately while still on grub menu. Once grub shows in this way, it persists to the OS.
- With GRUB and not unplug and replug the cable within grub menu, the display through VGA / HDMI appears only when the graphics driver is loaded in the operating system (thus taking care of multiple monitors).
- So, if I don't do the cable unplug and replug (while in grub menu) and the operating system (such as windows) lacks graphics driver, the laptop won't show display forever unless a reboot is done with the above steps.

When connected with HDMI , cable unplug and replug has the same effect as turn off monitor and re- turn on monitor.

The laptop is a cheap one and I'm not going to get a new display panel for it.

I need some automatic effect like VGA or HDMI cable unplug and replug just after GRUB menu appears for the grub menu to show up in this scenario. Can I do that with some grub command or a module?